# How to apply specific number of request with specific number of users on an application while performing load test

Tags: performance, jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing

I have to perform load testing using JMeter on an application and requirements are as below.

1. Need to send 5500 requests in the first hour with 50 users
2. Need to add 15 users next hour and requests should not go beyond 9100(5500 + 3600).
3. Need to add 15 more users for 3rd hour and request should be max 21700.

Note: Need to add 15 users every hour with 3600 requests and this test will run for total 10 hours.

Not applied anything.

Answer (score 0):

Once started each JMeter thread (virtual user) will begin executing Samplers as fast as it can.

If you want to limit JMeter's samplers execution rate you can do this using one of [JMeter Timers](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#timers), for your case suitable are:

1. [Constant Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Constant_Throughput_Timer)

   [image]
2. [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

   [image]
3. Or [Throughput Shaping Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-shaping-timer-plugin)

   [image]
   the latter one allows you to add more "steps" with the desired throughput values:

   [image]

Comment: i have added Thread Group for the first hour with 50 users:  Number of Threads : 50 Loop Count: 1, Duration: 3600 seconds. Added a "Constant Throughput Timer" to the first Thread Group with throughput per mint as 91.677777. Created 2nd Thread Group for the second hour with 65 users(50 existing+15 new): Number of Threads: 65 Loop Count: 1 Duration: 3600 seconds. Added a "Constant Throughput Timer" to the second Thread Group with throughput(In sample per mint)= 60.0 and 80 user for 3rd thread and "Constant Throughput Timer" with 60.0. Is it correct?

Comment: configurations can be seen here [https://youtu.be/NmkQ0kVFXBY]

Comment: Do i need to add multiple tread groups with single throughput shaping timer and add the HTTP samplers under each tread group? @Dmitri T [tag:JMeter] [tag:performance-testing] & [tag:load-testing]